# Is Ion-list supposed to automatically add an arrow on the list item?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

The Ionic 2 documentation makes it seem like the arrow automatically comes with it. It isn't working that way for me however.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#lists

```
<ion-list>
         <ion-item>
           <p>Terms Of Use</p>
         </ion-item>
         <ion-item>
           <p>Privacy Policy</p>
         </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The arrow you're talking about is the **Detail arrow** ([docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/Item/#detail-arrows)). Just like you can see in the docs:

> By default,  and  elements with the ion-item attribute will
>   display a right arrow icon **on ios mode**.

And

> To hide the right arrow icon on either of these elements, add the
>   `detail-none` attribute to the item. To show the right arrow icon on an
>   element that doesn't display it naturally, add the `detail-push`
>   attribute to the item.

Regarding Android and Windows phone,

> **This feature is not enabled by default for md and wp modes**, but it can
>   be enabled by setting the Sass variables `$item-md-detail-push-show` and
>   `$item-wp-detail-push-show`, respectively, to `true`. It can also be
>   disabled for ios by setting `$item-ios-detail-push-show` to `false`

So if you want to enable it for android and windows phone, you just need to add the following in your `variables.scss` file:

```
$item-md-detail-push-show: true;
$item-wp-detail-push-show: true;
```